# How to connection wamp host to remote sql server

Tags: php, mysql, dll, sqlsrv

I already uploaded following files in php C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext

1. php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll
2. php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
3. php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll

I also enable following things in php.ini

1. extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/"
2. [PHP_SQLSRV]
   extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
   extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll

But still i m getting error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

This is the code in my connection file :

```
$serverName = "xxx.xxx.xxx.x"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"xxxxx", "UID"=>"xxx", "PWD"=>"xxx");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) 
{
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}
else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: Did you restart your server, or better stop and start your sever and see any error message pop.

Comment: Yes i restart wamp. no any error found

Comment: Did you give permissions to those files on windows?